# Working with special cases of the converse of Lagrange's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am to answer true/false to statements on the form:

> Every abelian group of order divisible by $n$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $n$.

This follows directly from Cauchy's theorem when $n$ is prime. However, I am still not sure how to prove/disprove this in cases where $n$ is not prime.

EDIT: I feel like an elaboration is necessary. I know that it is false for some $n$ that are not prime, like $n = 4$. However, I want to know how I can check this in individual cases, like $n = 6$.

Comment: Hint: Klein 4-group

Comment: Check the Klein group $\;C_2\times C_2\;$ with $\;n=4\;$ ...or the group $\;C_2\times C_2\times C_2\;$ with $\;n=4\;$ ...

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is false for $n = 4$. I have also been told it is true for $n = 6$, but I do not understand why.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, do you know the Fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups (or even better": of finitely generated abelian groups)?

Comment: If the order of an abelian group is divisible by $\;6\;$ then the group has elements with order two and three (why?), and thus their product has order six. This much is true for any order which is the product of *different* primes.

Comment: We have been through it; yes. I am taking Abstract Algebra as an extra course, so I am falling slightly behind.

What I did conclude with was the following (before seeing your comment, so some confidence in that, I suppose): $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \sim \mathbb{Z}_6$, and since $2$ and $3$ are different primes, we have that 1) the group has elements of order two and three and 2) the group has an element of order six, since we can find one such element in $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, and, if I remember correctly, isomorphism is forced for such groups according to one of the

Comment: theorems you mentioned.